# Storing a character in a memory location in Assembly Language

Tags: string, assembly, replace, x86, character

I am trying to write a program in Assembly Language where it will replace all the letter 'T' in the string STRVAR with 'U' and place the new string in OUTPUT. I figured that I should store each character one by one in OUTPUT throughout the loop process although after doing several trial and error with mov, I already ran out of ideas on how to store a character in a new memory location.

```
STRVAR db "ACGTACGTCCCTTT",0
OUTPUT times 21 db 0

section .text
global CMAIN
CMAIN:
    ;write your code here

    lea esi, [STRVAR]
    
L1: 
    mov al, [esi]
    cmp al, 0
    JE FINISH
    cmp al, 'T'
    JE REPLACE
    JNE CONTINUE
    inc esi
    jmp L1
    
REPLACE:
    ;store character here
    inc esi
    jmp L1
    
CONTINUE:
    ;store character here
    inc esi
    jmp L1
    
FINISH:
    
    xor eax, eax
    ret
```

Comment: You could introduce another pointer, conventionally `edi`, for the output. Then just use a `mov`, like in your load but reversed. What is causing you problem?

Comment: @Jester I tried the solution you suggested although I am not sure if I have implemented it correctly because I introduced another pointer which is `lea edi, [OUTPUT]` and then added `mov byte [edi], 'U'` and `mov byte [edit], al` . Is there something that I had missed?

Comment: Those are correct (except for the typo). You also need to `inc edi`.

Comment: Oh thank you for pointing out the typo (I will make sure to correct that one) and I also did include the `inc edi` under L1, Replace, and Continue. The build is successful although every time I run the program, it crashes. Did I implemented it incorrectly?

Comment: Make sure you also have a `section .data` at the top otherwise your string will go into the default section which is `.text` and is read-only.

Comment: Thank you! I added `section .data` and it finally worked as intended!

Answer (score 2):

I followed the information shared by Jester and I finally get to have the program work based on what is stated in the specification. I realized I need to add `section .data` and introduced another point which in this case, `lea edi, [OUTPUT]` to store each character and use it to print a new string.

```
%include "io.inc"
section .data

STRVAR db "ACGTACGTCCCTTT",0
OUTPUT times 21 db 0

section .text

global CMAIN
CMAIN:
    ;write your code here

    lea esi, [STRVAR]
    lea edi, [OUTPUT]
    
L1: 
    mov al, [esi]
    cmp al, 0
    JE FINISH
    cmp al, 'T'
    JE REPLACE
    JNE CONTINUE
    inc esi
    inc edi
    jmp L1
    
REPLACE:
    mov byte[edi], 'U'
    inc esi
    inc edi
    jmp L1
    
CONTINUE:
    mov byte[edi], al
    inc esi
    inc edi
    jmp L1
    
FINISH:
    mov byte [edi], 0
    PRINT_STRING OUTPUT
    PRINT_DEC 1, [edi] ;check if the terminating 0 is also included
    xor eax, eax
    ret
```